# SMTP with TLS "by hand" in .NET

Tags: .net, ssl, smtp

I want to send email through an SMTP server but don't want to use the built-in `SmtpClient` class because it doesn't provide much control over the email headers.

I found [an example of sending SMTP mail in .NET](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030316.asp) that basically boils down to:

```
string server = "smtp.server.com";
int port = 25;

IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);
IPEndPoint endPt = new IPEndPoint(host.AddressList[0], port);

using (Socket s = new Socket(endPt.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)) {
    s.Connect(endPt);

    Action<string> Senddata = (string msg) => {
        byte[] _msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        s.Send(_msg, 0, _msg.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    };

    Senddata("HELO " + server);
    // Rest of email data elided
}
```

But presumably that won't work for a connection that requires TLS, like Gmail's SMTP servers.

Is there a straightfoward way to do this kind of exchange over an explicit SSL connection, e.g. using the `STARTTLS` SMTP command? I don't know much about the SSL protocol and certainly don't want to get bogged down trying to write my own implementation. I'm hopeful there's a way to use the `SslStream` class or something to send the data.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need to do that SmtpClient can't?

Comment: I want to have the email's "To" header have different contents than the SMTP's "RCPT" field. The .NET `SmtpClient` uses the `MailMessage.To` property for both values and doesn't let you override headers.

Comment: You can use third-party SMTP component for this. SecureBlackbox and Rebex libraries include one.